# React-Autosuggest, validation with Yup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, autosuggest, yup

I'm trying to integrate React-Autosuggest (https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) with Yup, Formik and Material-UI.

It would be enough for me to have that Yup show the error message under the autosuggest, on the onValidate() event.

Like this:

[image]

Using
formik.validateForm()
I can see that Yup correctly validates the value of my Autosuggest (it's included in the array of invalid fields), but it does not render the error message below the form.

I was wondering if Yup expects a specific HTML to show the error message.

Comment: Yup doesn't expect anything to be present in the HTML, it is Formik that has that requirement. You should be able to import an `ErrorMessage` component from Formik which will automatically hook into the form state and show an error message for the specified component. Does that answer your question?